# How to take in a string and use it as a variable assigning it an empty list

Tags: python-3.x

So here is what I want to do...:
I have a `keyList = ['age', 'occupation', 'education']`
and I want to create this:

```
age = []
occupation = []
education = []
```

and the elements of keyList are arbitrary and if the words were to change then the list names were to change as well.
How would I code this?
Not a hardcore python programmer, just taking first year computing. Hopefully nothing too complicated to understand.

This is the link for a picture of the assignment details:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/chRTl.jpg

Comment: Please explain what you need that for. It seems likely that you are approaching your wider problem the wrong way. Objects themselves do not have names in Python, there can be many names referring to the same object.

Comment: First, I would recommend against this. Second, this is probably possible, but far more complex than is appropriate for your stated level of experience. Can you describe why you want to do this, so maybe we can help you out with the final goal?

Comment: Even if you achieve to dynamically define variables depending on a list of strings, how do you plan to use them without typing?

Comment: I have attached the picture of the assignment details

Comment: @BenjaminHui At which point of this assignment do you think you need to define lists with these names? Apparently you are already provided the read data set in some form. You can probably work with it directly.

Comment: So what I am planning to do is since the keys which have a value of strings I have to convert to ratio values, I need separate lists since the loop goes through one set at a time.

Comment: @BenjaminHui What format is the data in currently? A dictionary of lists for each attribute or a list of dictionaries?

Comment: @uneven_mark this is what the data looks like http://research.cs.queensu.ca/home/cords2/annualIncome.txt

Comment: @BenjaminHui No, I am talking about the data, after it is read into the python.

Comment: The data is within a large list inside it 37,000 dictionaries for example [{'age': 23 , 'occupation': 'banker'}]

Comment: @BenjaminHui Then the question you should ask is something like: "I have a dataset in the form of a list of dictionaries, for example: [...] How do I calculate [...] from it. I tried/thought about doing [...] but don't know how to/got errors/wrong results [...]" (fill out the [...] with details) Your approach in this question is not at all going to make this easier.

Comment: ok Sorry I need help on the question.

Comment: @BenjaminHui You should probably make it a new question, in the format I recommended. I did not understand what particular *"ratio"* you want to calculate and how it relates to loops.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do that:

```
>>> key_list = ['age', 'occupation', 'education']
>>> for key in key_list:
...     exec(f'{key} = []')
... 
>>> age
[]
```

On the other hand, I'm not sure this is exactly what you want/need to do, and using `exec` or `eval` is often recommended against.

Comment: That doesn't address the need for the variable names to change when the string values in the original list change.